# Pass Data to Be Used in Android Webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I am programming an Android app that uses the javascript version of Google Maps and loads it right up into an Android webview. My issue is that I need to somehow pass multiple longitude and latitude values that will be gotten at the time of execution through a JSON query. I know that I could hard code them if they were static, but because they are gotten at the time of execution I am kind of stuck as to how to append this data to the html file that is being WebView-ed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by appending the data to the HTML file? Do you mean that you get latitude and longitude in Java and need a way to inject them to the page being displayed in the WebView?